# Problema del Plugin com.hpe.alm.OctaneGherkinFormatter

Tags: java, selenium, java-8, testing, cucumber

He actualizado la versión de **cucumber core a la 7.9.0** . Al ejecutar un caso de prueba da un error de mi plugin para sacar los reports:  `The plugin specification 'com.hpe.alm.octane.OctaneGherkinFormatter:**/target/gherkin-results/ManualRunnerTest_OctaneGherkinResults.xml' has a problem:(..)`
Mis plugins nuevos que he añadido en el POM son estos:

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>com.hpe.alm.octane</groupId>
            <artifactId>octane-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>15.1.0</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microfocus.adm.almoctane.bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>bdd2octane</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
   <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microfocus.adm.almoctane.bdd</groupId>
            <artifactId>octane-cucumber-jvm</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

No se si me falta algún plugin más o es la configuración donde ejecuto el plugin desde RunMainTest:

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"pretty", "summary",
        "html:target/test-report-1",
        "json:target/test-report-1.json",
        "junit:target/test-report-1.xml",
        "timeline:target/cucumber-timeline-1",
        "com.hpe.alm.octane.OctaneGherkinFormatter:target/gherkin-results/ManualRunnerTest_OctaneGherkinResults.xml"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimado el plugins de ALM octane no es compatabible con versiones superiores de cucumber 7. Existe un jar que te permite generar el xml https://github.com/MicroFocus/bdd2octane pero no lo encuentro muy recomendable ya que tendrias que generarlo afuera del proyecto.

En cmd:

```
java -jar C:/Users/user/Desktop/ejecutable/bdd2octane-1.1.0.jar --reportFiles="**/results/*.xml" --featureFiles="**/src/test/resources/features/" --resultFile="cucumber-jvm-result2.xml" --framework="cucumber-jvm"
```